# Unable to load image using Coil from content URI

Tags: android, image, android-jetpack-compose, android-glide, coil

I am trying to load an image who's (mimeType is video/mp4) using **coil** in my Android app from a content URI.

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
val mediaPath = "content://media/external/file/252819" // its mimeType is video/mp4

AsyncImage(
    model = mediaPath,
    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.thumbnail),
    placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_default_thumbnail),
    error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_default_thumbnail),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(1f),
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)
```

Even i also try to load it using **rememberAsyncImagePainter**:

```
val imagePainter = 
            rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(data = media.mediaPath).apply(block = fun ImageRequest.Builder.() {
                    placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_thumbnail)
                    error(R.drawable.ic_default_thumbnail)
                }).build()
            )

        Image(
            painter = imagePainter,
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.thumbnail),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
```

Despite using the correct content URI and providing the necessary placeholder and error resources, I am unable to successfully load the thumbnail image. I have verified that the content URI is valid and refers to an existing video file.

**Note:** I have the required permissions to access the content URI and have ensured that the content URI is correct.

Comment: "mimeType is video/mp4" -- that is not an image. It is a video. You would need to look into [Coil's video support](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/videos/) if you want to grab a frame of the video as an image.

Comment: How Glide works perfect in this case?

Comment: [The Glide documentation has](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) "Glide supports fetching, decoding, and displaying video stills, images, and animated GIFs.". Perhaps they include the equivalent of Coil's video support in the core Glide library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this LoadThumbnail method to load the image/video thumbnail by using **coil**:

```
@Composable
fun LoadThumbnail(
    mediaPath: String,
    isVideo: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    if (isVideo) {
        val imageLoader = remember {
            ImageLoader.Builder(context)
                .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .respectCacheHeaders(true)
                .components {
                    add(VideoFrameDecoder.Factory())
                }
                .crossfade(true)
                .build()
        }
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = mediaPath,
        imageLoader = imageLoader,
    )

    if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_default_thumbnail),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = modifier,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        )
    }

    Image(
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.thumbnail),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = modifier
    )
} else {
    AsyncImage(
        model = mediaPath,
        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.thumbnail),
        modifier = modifier,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_default_thumbnail),
        error = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_default_thumbnail)
    )
}
}
```